# In Assembly, doesn't the quotient and remainder go to AL,AH? What happens here?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I was searching for a hex-to-decimal piece of code on the net and I stumbled upon this. I tested it and it works perfectly although I don't understand why.

```
DATA SEGMENT
 NUM DW 01FH
 BUFFER  DB 10 DUP ('$')
 DATA ENDS
 CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME DS:DATA,CS:CODE
START:       
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

MOV AX,NUM

LEA SI,BUFFER
CALL HEX2DEC

LEA DX,BUFFER
MOV AH,9
INT 21H 

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H        
CODE ENDS
HEX2DEC PROC NEAR
MOV CX,0
MOV BX,10

LOOP1: 
   MOV DX,0       
   DIV BX ;<--------------------------------
   ADD DL,30H ;<----------???
   PUSH DX
   INC CX
   CMP AX,9
   JA LOOP1

   ADD AL,30H
   MOV [SI],AL

   LOOP2: 
   POP AX
   INC SI
   MOV [SI],AL
   LOOP LOOP2
   RET
   HEX2DEC ENDP           

   END START
```

Although the division happened, this guy used DL instead of AL and just pushed it to the stack like that. How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) is pretty clear on this:

> `DIV r/m16` Unsigned divide `DX:AX` by `r/m16`, with **result
>   stored in `AX` ← Quotient, `DX` ← Remainder**.

As you can see if you look up the `DIV` instruction in the manual, the exact registers used for the dividend, quotient, and remainder depends on the size of the operand.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your quick reply.
What do you mean by unsigned?
I mean, where in this code can someone understand if it is unsigned or singed?

Comment: It means that the operands are treated as unsigned values. If you want to perform a division where the operands are treated as signed you should use `IDIV`.

Comment: My professor always used "DIV CL". Because CL is 8-bit the results were being stored to AL,AH. I checked it on emu8086 and that's how it is.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `DIV r/m8` divides `AX` by `r/m8` and stores the quotient in `AL` and the remainder in `AH`.